# Generate two select optionboxes doesn't work properly

Tags: mysql, sql

In my HTML I have two select boxes generated in PHP. The options in the second select box(loadscripts) need to be generated from the input of the first selectbox (vboxes).

```
<div class="style-selected">
        <form id="select_vbox" name="select_vbox" method="post" action="<?php echo($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
          <h1>Virtualboxes</h1>;
          <select class="styled-select" id="vboxes" name="vboxes" size="15">;
          <?php
            $virtualbox = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Virtualbox WHERE user_id = ".$_SESSION['user_id']);
            while($select = mysql_fetch_array($virtualbox)){
              echo("<option value=" . $select["titel"] . ">" . $select["titel"] . "</option>");
            }
            echo("</select>");

            echo("<h1>Loadscripts</h1>");
            echo("<select class=\"styled-select\" id=\"loadscripts\" name=\"loadscripts\" size=\"15\">");

            echo("</select>");

          ?>
          <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK"></p>
        </form>
        </div>
```

Then I have some PHP code called ajax-getvalues.php:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect(host, username, password);
mysql_select_db($connection, db);

$selectvalue = mysql_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['svalue']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT loadscriptnaam FROM Loadscripts WHERE vbox_md5 = 'jn12jcbhwer34hbhj32b4j'");

echo '<option value="">Please select...</option>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['loadscriptnaam'].'">' . $row['loadscriptnaam'] . "</option>";
  }

mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

And finally some jquery in my HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var list_target_id = 'loadscripts'; //first select list ID
  var list_select_id = 'vboxes'; //second select list ID
  var initial_target_html = '<option value="">Selecteer een virtualbox...</option>'; //Initial prompt for target select

  $('#'+list_target_id).html(initial_target_html); //Give the target select the prompt option

  $('#'+list_select_id).change(function(e) {
    //Grab the chosen value on first select list change
    var selectvalue = $(this).val();

    //Display 'loading' status in the target select list
    $('#'+list_target_id).html('<option value="">Een moment geduld...</option>');

    if (selectvalue == "") {
        //Display initial prompt in target select if blank value selected
       $('#'+list_target_id).html(initial_target_html);
    } else {
      //Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
      $.ajax({url: 'ajax-getvalues.php?svalue='+selectvalue,
             success: function(output) {
                //alert(output);
                $('#'+list_target_id).html(output);
            },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
          }});
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that the second select box doesn't return any data.

Comment: You mean the second select gets filled in correctly, but it doesn't get submitted with the form?

Comment: No before I submit the form, the second select box need to be generated. @Barmar

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console? Do you see the correct returned data in the Network tab? What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
Attr.specified is deprecated. Its value is always true. these are the only errors... @barmar

Comment: Those warnings are both known jQuery issues and can be ignored.

Comment: Do you see the correct returned data in the Network tab?

Comment: I think I know what the problem is.. but still not the answer. It seems that my PHP script doesn't 'save' the selected GET value.. I don't know why and I don't know how either.. @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

You have the arguments to some of the `mysql` functions in the wrong order -- you're using them as if they were the analogous `mysqli` functions.

```
$connection = mysql_connect(host, username, password);
mysql_select_db(db, $connection);

$selectvalue = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['svalue'], $connection);
```

In `mysql`, the connection argument is optional (it defaults to the last connection opened), so it always comes last.

Your query should be:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT loadscriptnaam FROM Loadscripts WHERE vbox_md5 = '$selectvalue'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Note the quotes around `$selectvalue`, assuming it's a string.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but nevertheless the $selectvalue isn't returning any data. There is one but! When I write the following:
echo '<option value="">'.$selectvalue.'</option>'; it returns the actual GET value.. I'm a bit confused now..

Comment: Your query isn't using `$selectvalue`.

Comment: It isn't working when i put the $selectvalue in a query

Comment: Please correct the question to show how you're using `$selectvalue`.

Comment: What do i have to do to put that GET value in a query?

Comment: I don't know, what is it supposed to be used for?

Comment: The code I'm currently using is from [link](http://www.webdevdoor.com/javascript-ajax/dynamic-select-list-jquery-php/) The code i'm using: $selectvalue = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['svalue'], $connection);
 
mysql_select_db("$db_name");
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Virtualbox WHERE virtualboxnaam = "$selectvalue"');

Comment: So the $selectvalue is to use it eventually in a query

Comment: And how does it related to the table you're querying? What column is it supposed to match?

Comment: i'm sorry i'm kinda new to this as you can see.. the query I wrote wasn't correct (i'm so sorry for your time..) But thanks alot!